# How do you make whitespace in a single line of string?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner to any type of coding. Right now my class is learning Python and I'm having trouble printing out a string the assignment wants.

Output the following figure with asterisks. Do not add spaces after the last character in each line.

```
*****
*   *
*****
*   *
*****
```

I have everything correct except for the whitespace. I'm not sure how to put that large of a space between the two asterisks.

```
print('*****')
print('*',   '*')
```

Comment: You can put a space directly in string: `print('*   *')`...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Looks like you forgot to post the code you're having trouble with! :)

Answer (score 2):

You could just print the whole thing at once.

```py
print("""\
*****
*   *
*****
*   *
*****""")
```

This triple quote behavior is described [here in the documentation for strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

---

I should also point out that the answer to your root question is just to include the space in the string. `print("* * *")`

Answer (score 2):

You could also do it with just one `print()` function call. You just have to do:

```
print("""*****
*   *
*****
*   *
*****""")
```

The triple quotation marks (`"""`) designate a multi-line string.
So, you could also do it like this:

```
s = """*****
*   *
*****
*   *
*****"""
print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to base the number of spaces off some programmatic value (e.g., a constant, some number you calculate, etc.), you can also use the Python string repetition capability:

```py
TOTAL_SPACES = 5
print('*' + (TOTAL_SPACES * ' ') + '*') # prints: *     *
```

Or, using f-strings:

```py
print(f'*{TOTAL_SPACES * " "}*')
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome! You could simply have five print statements like this:

```
print('*****')
print('*   *')
print('*****')
print('*   *')
print('*****')
```

or you could use more elegant ways...
Python supports repeating characters in print statements - this will produce five asterisks:

```
print('*' * 5)
```

Also, rather than having separate print statements, you could include the newline character \n with the multiple prints described above to get your output with a single line of code like this:

```
print('*' * 5 + '\n*   *\n' + '*' * 5 + '\n*   *\n' + '*' * 5)
```

Enjoy learning Python - it's an awesome language!

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun:

```
for i in range(5):
    print(('*****', '*   *')[i%2])
```

**Output:**

```
*****
*   *
*****
*   *
*****
```

Comment: That's beautiful! +1 for finding a way to do it with a loop...